# Python undesirable complex numbers

Tags: python

```
>>> a = -27
>>> a ** (1/3)
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
>>> -27 ** (1/3)
-3.0
```

I have to raise numbers of the list to a power 1/3 but when the number is negative   I get a complex number. Why is there such difference in results of these two operations and how can I avoid the first one?

Answer (score 1):

When you set `a=-27`, you are assigning the negative to the value as well.  When you just type in `-27**(1/3)` it computes the exponent first and then the negative sign.  This may be the reason for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your order of operations; power has precedence over unary minus.

```
-27 ** (1/3)
```

evaluates as

```
- (27 ** (1/3))
```

not as

```
(-27) ** (1/3)    # gives a complex result
```

If `a` is negative, to get a real root, you need to do

```
-(-a)**(1/3)
```

Comment: This doesn't gel with what Python 2.7 is giving me. `(-27) ** (1/3)` gives me `1`.

Comment: Doh, integer division...

Comment: Python 2 assumes `/` is integer division unless one of the operands is a float. Try `(1./3)` instead.

Comment: @HughBothwell and then if you try (-27)**(1./3) it will raise a ValueError saying "ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power"

Comment: Hmm... so it does, even 2.7.13. Python 3 accepts it quite happily. Try -(27**(1./3)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A complex number `z` has 3 roots of `z**3` so for `z**(1/3)` it's necessary to pick one. A conventional choice is the so-called principal value of `z**(1/3)` which has the least argument (i.e. it is the one which has the smallest angle with respect to the positive real axis). As you have found, that has nonzero imaginary part when `z` is a negative real number.

My advice is to just have a test such as `if (z < 0): -((-z)**(1/3)) else: z**(1/3)` (sorry if I got the wrong syntax).